# Terrible Frame Rate In Games

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, gaming, framerate

I recently acquired a new graphics card (NIVIDIA GeForce GTX745 4GB) a upgrade from my last (ZOCTAC GTX 950 2GB). I was quite content when i fit it and every thing was working. So i loaded up my game tom clancy ghost recon wildlands. Normaly play it fine 30frames max on low graphics and frequent frame drops. Since I've put this new card in my FPS is even worse 16FPS on medium settings. It seems to be the same with most of my games graphics look abit better but my frames are terrible. My operating system is windows 10

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and 1/ Add a proper title, 2/ Add the correct tags for your operating system.

Comment: Your question is still really broad.  Does your system meet the recomended requirements for the program your trying to run?  It might be the minimum requirements, which means, "terrible frame rates" might actually be expected.  Please take the time to make your question clear.  Your screenshot doesn't tell us what CPU you have.  Post the recomended and minimum requirements for the program your attempting to run while you are at it.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this... you bought a card less than half as fast as your old one & you're wondering why it's slower???? Quick fix. Put your old card back in.

Comment: If you look at the [current lineup](http://international.download.nvidia.com/webassets/en_US/shared/images/products/shared/lineup-full.png) it's likely that your "new card", while it does have more VRAM, does have less performance than your old card. The fancy graphics budget slider only checks the VRAM amount and doesn't do anything to check the performance of the card.

Comment: General rule for NVidia, the first digit is the 'year' the second two digits are the 'speed'. So you bought a card 2 years older & 'a bit' slower', which when you take the 'year' into consideration & also the fact that any NVidia ending in a 5 [rather than 0] means  a 'cheap, cut-down version' you simply bought a much slower, older card.

Comment: the 745 is slower compared to the 950: http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=2843&cmp%5B%5D=3295

Comment: @magicandre1981 Several magnitudes slower in fact.  The fact it has 4GB is meaningless type of performance difference between a 745 and 940

Answer (score 6):

The [Geforce 745](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce%20GTX%20745&id=2843) is extremely old card from 2014, which is [half as fast of the Geforce 950](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=2843&cmp%5B%5D=3295)

[image]

Get a newer [Geforce GTX 1060 to get a large improvement](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=2843&cmp%5B%5D=3295&cmp%5B%5D=3548).

[image]